# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND & ECONNRESET node.js, playframework, mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, playframework, java-8

I've seen the same question posted more than a dozen times, and I've verified my code against answers to all of those.

In a nutshell, here is the request response cycle:

browser event -> call goes to node.js server -> node.js orchestrator -> LB -> java microservices (APIs) -> mongo DB , and all the way back.

I have a node.js 'orchestrator' which routes the requests to the proxy(load balancer -> each route added in the httpd.conf). Each of the services is deployed into a two-node cluster.

The occurrence of 'ENOTFOUND' & 'ECONNRESET' seem to be random. There logs indicate that after a number of repeated error responses (e.g. login failure) the socket simply gets hung up.

I pass options, and http.get(option, callback). The 'http' is never added to the host also.
On an average I get one socket hangup everyday.

Comment: Where do you see the error messages? Which logs are you looking at? Are you able to replicate? More info and detail please.

Comment: Hello Rich, thank you for your reply, and sorry about the delay in replying. I'm seeing the errors in orchestrator's logs. I'm not able to replicate if I try. However, I wait for an hour or two and I can see the 'enotfound' error. I will share more logs today. I've installed longjohn but the logs are not detailed yet. I'm going to have to fix that first.